# Debian 12 install failed to install grub boot loader and now will only boot into grub and won't dpkg

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub, dpkg

Hardware:
Mini PC
Intel 12th Gen Alder Lake- N95
8GB DDR4 RAM
256GB PCIe 1X SSD

Tried to install Debian 12 on whole system from flash but failed to install boot loader and now only boots into grub. Can access system by typing into grub:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-5-amd64 root=/dev/nvme0n1p2
initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-5-amd64
boot
```

I want to try to reinstall from USB but can't figure out how to get rid of grub on boot up to reinstall and can't figure out how to boot into usb install from grub. Any guidance would be great.

Tried to install curl but received error while in system from dpkg:

```
warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable.
2 expected program(s) not found in PATH or not executable.
root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI#Force_grub-efi_installation_to_the_removable_media_path